# Plot zeroes of polyomial in $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ in Linux

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, math-software

I have a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$, say $$p_c(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-xyz-c.$$
Do you know any simple piece of software to plot the zeroes of this polynomial using Linux? In the past I plotted similar pictures with Grapher on a Mac, but I really need to do this on a Linux machine.

Thank you!

Comment: http://surf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Have you tried to do a google search with the keywords "linux graphing software" or "linux plotting software"?

Comment: already tried wolfram alpha? if it should be free, try octave. otherwise  try matlab, maple, and so on.